# how to crawl post posed in a closed group on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to crawl posts from a closed group I have joined. I read the facebook api but I still do not know how to solve this problem. I read this thread [Facebook API / httpclient wrapper for crawling through the wall posts & group posts of any user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112253/facebook-api-httpclient-wrapper-for-crawling-through-the-wall-posts-group-po) . But it is old and no good answers are provided.

Comment: If you need more instructions, just leave the msg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Graph API Explorer to test your code

Basically, you can send http request to access the data by

GET

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{group-id}/feed?access_token={token}
```

### Update :

You can no longer use this endpoint until an admin of such group [install your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api#app-installation) on it.
It is also necessary that your app goes through the [**Facebook App Review process**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api#app-review).

Comment: Is it still possible?

Comment: That's not possible anymore. You can do it only for public groups.

Answer (score 2):

update in 2019: you can not get data from group fb because they added a new permission and you have to verify your application with them.

Comment: Even if you get permission to use the Groups API, I believe you can only access post data from groups the user is an administrator of.

Comment: yes, it is very difficult now. You have an application and wait for their verify. And if you use https://graph.facebook.com/{group-id}/feed?access_token={token} , it is only for public group, not private group. If you want to craw private or public, i suggest to use chrome extensions.. i got it success

Comment: @huy may i know which chrome extension you are using?

Comment: @huy I would also be interested in what extension you meant.

Comment: i use Data Scraper.. (data miner)